# Как сделать after content по центру?

Tags: css

Решил попробовать применить html+css для отображения простых математических формул. Плюс ("+") между двумя высокими блоками опускается вниз. Не пойму как его можно отцентрировать по вертикали с помощью css. И еще нижняя граница рисуется над плюсом между дробями: вылезает чуть правее.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.sum>div:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: "+";
}
div.div>div:nth-child(1) {
  clear: right;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sum">
    <div class="div">
        <div class="sum">
            <div>21</div>
            <div>37</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sum">
            <div>12</div>
            <div>22</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div">
        <div class="sum">
            <div>123</div>
            <div>456</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sum">
            <div>12</div>
            <div>555</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Буду также благодарен за ссылки по теме.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если только так, хотя думаю есть и другие способы.

```css
  div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
  div.sum > div:nth-child(1)::after {
    content: "+";
  }
  div.div > div:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    clear: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .formula > div.sum > div::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: -11px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .formula > div.sum > div:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="formula">
  <div class="sum">
    <div class="div">
      <div class="sum">
        <div>21</div>
        <div>37</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sum">
        <div>12</div>
        <div>22</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div">
      <div class="sum">
        <div>123</div>
        <div>456</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sum">
        <div>12</div>
        <div>555</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```